# Insert every tuple in a list to another tuple so I will have a list of tuples of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples, python-3.6

I am trying to convert the following list of tuples to a list that contains tuples of the original tuples.
For example we have the following list:

```
arr1 = [(1, 2), (2, 3), (4, 5)]
```

I tried to do the following conversion but it didn't work:

```
arr1_tuples = [tuple(item) for item in arr1]
```

The desired output is:

```
[((1, 2)), ((2, 3)), ((4, 5))]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your desired output is impossible (single element `tuple`s will have a `repr` with a trailing comma), but your desired data structure is achievable with:

```
arr1_tuples = [(item,) for item in arr1]
```

That wraps each `item` in a one-`tuple`. The parentheses aren't necessary, but the lone trailing comma is easy to miss without them.

The result, if `print`ed, would be:

```
[((1, 2),), ((2, 3),), ((4, 5),)]
      # ^          ^          ^ Commas unavoidable in one-tuples; otherwise matches request
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `map`:

```
arr1 = [(1, 2), (2, 3), (4, 5)]

arr1_tuples = map(lambda x:(x,), arr1)

print(list(arr1_tuples))
```

Output:

```
[((1, 2),), ((2, 3),), ((4, 5),)]
```

`lambda x:(x,)` will take in an element, and return it inside a tuple.

Comment: There's no reason to use `map` when it'll require a `lambda` to operate (that an equivalent listcomp/genexpr could avoid). It's more verbose and slower than the equivalent. `map` is largely useful only when you have an existing function that does what you need, ideally implemented in C (if it's not implemented in C, `map` won't provide a meaningful performance boost over listcomp/genexpr equivalent).